# .net MVC Master Detail View with associated records

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am looking to make a Master Detail View.

I have two tables tbFamily and tbFamilyMember.

I am currently able to view the Family Details and list the associated family members, however, I want to seperate the Family Members based on their Role. i.e. I want to display a list of the Parents/Guardians and then a list of the children ordered by Date of Birth.

My Models are as follows:

```
public class tbFamily
{
    public int tbFamilyID { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<tbFamilyMember> tbFamilyMember { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tbFamilyData> tbFamilyData { get; set; }
}

public class tbFamilyMember
{
    public int tbFamilyMemberID { get; set; }
    public int tbFamilyID { get; set; }
    public int Role { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public char Gender { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public virtual tbFamily tbFamily { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller currently looks as follows:

```
    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        tbFamily tbfamily = db.tbFamily.Find(id);
        if (tbfamily == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(tbfamily);
    }
```

Its associated View

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Surname)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address1)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address2)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address3)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Town)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.County)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Postcode)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Country)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Telephone)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Mobile)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)

@foreach (var item in Model.tbFamilyMember)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Firstname)
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Surname)
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Role)
}
```

To Get the Children:

```
public ActionResult GetChildren(int id)
{
    var tbFamilyData = from f in db.tbFamilyMember
                       where f.tbFamilyID.Equals(id)
                       where f.Role.Equals(3)
                       select f;
        return View(tbFamilyData);
}
```

Its associated View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.tbFamilyData)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tbFamilyMember.Firstname)
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tbFamilyMember.Surname)
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tbFamilyMember.Role)
}
```

Just not sure how to get the two working together!

I have created a seperate Model tbFamilyData

```
public class tbFamilyData
{
    public virtual tbFamily tbFamily { get; set; }
    public virtual tbFamilyMember tbFamilyMember { get; set; }
}
```

I am now getting the error tbFamilyData has no key defined.

Hoping someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest one of two options:

1)  create viewmodels that better represent your views, and fill them in the controller (my preferred solution).

```
public class FamilyViewModel 
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    ... // other props

    public ICollection<FamilyMemberViewModel> Parents { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FamilyMemberViewModel> Children { get; set; }
}
```

2)  use Linq methods in your view to filter the data to display

```
<h1>Parents</h1>
@foreach (var item in Model.tbFamilyMember.Where(x => x.Role == Roles.Parent))
{
    ...
}

<h1>Children</h1>
@foreach (var item in Model.tbFamilyMember.Where(x => x.Role == Roles.Child)
                                          .OrderBy(x => x.DateOfBirth))
{
    ...
}
```